# Can't access the device camera from appmaker?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have been able to use the device camera in JavaScript as many have illustrated. I have not been able to access the device camera from Google App Maker. If it is possible, could someone share the App Maker script that actually works.

This script does result in the question about using the camera but the video doesn't show up in the PiCeMTakePhotos image widget.

```
var video = app.pages.PiCeMTakePhotos.descendants.videoWindow;
const constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: true
};

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // make stream available to browser console 
  video.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', 
  error.message, error.name);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
```

Comment: I'll be happy to help. Can you please post a complete example of what you've tried? I need to see your code and also know what and how you are trying to do things to better help you.

Comment: var video = app.pages.PiCeMTakePhotos.descendants.videoWindow;
const constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: true
};

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  window.stream = stream; // make stream available to browser console 
  video.srcObject = stream;
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.log('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);

Comment: The problem here is that the video variable refers to an appmaker widget. That wont work. You have to use a `video` element. You will need to use an HTML widget and create a video element inside of it.

Comment: Thanks for all your guidance. I have experience with IOS apps and I am a beginner with app maker. Could you point me in the direction of the mechanics of embedding HTML in app maker. I don't see what may be obvious.

Comment: Solved the camera access problem. Works fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm happy to know you were able to solve the problem. Maybe you should post the solution as answer for future references.

Comment: Could anyone explain why the camera mentioned above, works fine on Chrome on a Mac but not on chrome on an iPad?

Comment: What do you mean? It works great on my end on both iPad and Tablets...but oh boy! Can't really express how much I hate apple products so I'll just stay away from this thread.

Comment: The ipad is Gsuite managed. It is likely that is the sorce of not getting to the camera. Thanks.